# Storing Images in Database (Address vs. Blob)

Tags: mysql, database

I am planning on working on a personal project over the summer that I feel I might be able to complete now that I have the understanding of databases. I want to have a database that is able to be filtered down on say attributes an image has.

For example, we have a database of images of cars. I want to see only images for Chevy. So I click on the "Chevy" tab. I want to be able to query data for Chevy and show images for only chevy cars.

I can structure my database that if I'm on "Chevy" it goes to "chevy" table correct?

I am yet to work on a real world model, so completely new to me.

From what I have understood you can store images in database as "Blob", but it sounds like it might be more preferable to store these images in a host directory on my website server, and store the path to them instead.

I want to ultimately expand this out to an mobile app for Android and IoS, I dont imagine that would affect the decision to much. But is a plan I would like to try and incorporate also later down the road.

Currently I am going to try and do a website application, then I'll work on a mobile app afterwords.

Popular database's seem to be Mongo, any other recommended for a beginner programmer?

Comment: Don't create Chevy table. Create a table of cars. One column could be `Make`, which would have Chevy. Another column could be `Model`, which would have information like Impala. Another column called `BuiltYear`. Another column called `ImagePath` and so on. When user clicks Chevy, query the table using `where Make='Chevy'` I recommend MySQL for database and 
PHP/HTML/CSS/jQuery for web for beginners. All the best.

Comment: Would we not want a Foreign key from a table called Model, or Manufacture? Wouldn't that give us the best data structure?

Comment: With the table called say "cars" would we want the image a blob or url to destination on the server. The only thing I'm worried about if I do server url is if the structure ever changes, or I change host. Would large amount of images affect this?

Comment: You certainly can and should in production. While you are testing and building applications for personal use, don't make the database too complex or normalized. Just keep it simple and make it work. Once things are working right, then normalize it further.

Comment: I'd store the images on the server, as you mentioned in your question. It's an easier approach and you can view the files on the file system without the need to query them out of the database.